# Conditional: if verb be + adjective, is it referred to the past?

Tags: conditionals, present-tense

Sentences:

Terms of a competition (2018): *nothing*.

Terms of a competition (2019): *If the athlete is awarded, he will not be considered for future competitions.*

For example: if I was awarded in 2018 and the terms of the competition are new. Do I have to expect not to be considered for that competition? because is *If the athlete is awarded* referred to something that happened in the past or in the future? If I was awarded in the past, is the new condition true?

Comment: Hi Edoardo It is difficult to understand your question. The *term* of something means how long it lasts. The *terms* of entering a competition means the rules or conditions of the competition. Rewarded and awarded are different words. Please rewrite your question carefully, or give us some context. Thanks.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian thank you I did’t notice that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, if one is awarded, it doesn't really refer to the past, but the status that one is an awardee.  There is nothing wrong, grammatically.

Comment: Thanks, Does it mean that I could attend the competition in 2018?

Comment: You were awarded in 2017, and till 2018 the eligibility remained unconditional. A condition is being attached only in 2019. This needs to be clarified with the issuing office, though as on today, it refers to a past opportunity.

Comment: Is  the word   awarded   correct  in  the  sentence?

Comment: @RamPillai Thank you, but I don't understand. Could "if the athlete is awarded" to be referred to the past? If I was awarded in 2018 is the condition true?